# How to use Jenkins Pipeline global variable on another stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

I have defined global variable in Jenkins pipeline

```
def BUILDNRO = '0'
pipeline { ...
```

Then i manipulate variable with shell script to enable running builds parallel by using job build number as identifier so we don't mix different docker swarms.

```
    stage('Handle BUILD_NUMBER') {
        steps {
            script {
            BUILDNRO = sh( script: '''#!/bin/bash
            Build=`echo ${BUILD_NUMBER} | grep -o '..$'`
            # Check if BUILD first character is 0
            if [[ $Build:0:1 == "0" ]]; then
                # replace BUILD first character from 0 to 5
                Build=`echo $Build | sed s/./5/1`
            fi
            echo $Build
            ''',returnStdout: true).trim()
            }
        }
    }
```

i get value out from previos stage and trying to get global variable on next stage

```
    stage('DOCKER: Init docker swarm') {
        steps {
            echo "BUILDNRO is: ${BUILDNRO}"  --> Value is here.
            sh '''#!/bin/bash
            echo Buildnro is: ${BUILDNRO}   --> This is empty.
            ...
        }
    }
```

This will out give global variable empty. why? in previous stage there was value in it.

**EDIT 1.**
Modified code blocks to reflect current status.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to figure it out. Here is solution how i managed to did it.
BUILDNRO is groovy variable and if wanting to used in bash variable it have to pass using withEnv. BUILD_NUMBER in first stage is bash variable hence it can be used directly script in first stage.

```
def BUILDNRO = '0'

pipeline {
  ....
  stages {
    stage('Handle BUILD_NUMBER') {
      steps {
        script {
          BUILDNRO = sh( script: '''#!/bin/bash
          Build=`echo ${BUILD_NUMBER} | grep -o '..$'`
          ''',returnStdout: true).trim()
        }
      }
    }
    stage('DOCKER: Init docker swarm') {
      steps {
        dir("prose_env/prose_api_dev_env") {
          withEnv(["MYNRO=${BUILDNRO}"]) {
            sh(returnStdout: false, script: '''#!/bin/bash
            echo Buildnro is: ${MYNRO}`
            '''.stripIndent())
          }
        }
      }     
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using single quotes(```) in the shell module, Jenkins treats every variable as a bash variable. The solution is using double quotes(""") but then if you made bash variable you have to escape it. Below an example with working your use case and escaped bash variable

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Handle BUILD_NUMBER') {
            steps {
                script {
                    BUILDNRO = sh(script: 'pwd', returnStdout: true).trim()
                    echo "BUILDNRO is: ${BUILDNRO}"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('DOCKER: Init docker swarm') {
            steps {
                sh """#!/bin/bash
            echo Buildnro is: ${BUILDNRO}
            variable=world
            echo "hello \${variable}"
            sh """
            }
        }

    }
}
```

output of the second stage:

```
Buildnro is: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/stack1
hello world
```

Comment: Just curious as ${BUILD_NUMBER} is environment variable which is used in "Handle BUILD_NUMBER" stage. BUILDNRO is global variable which isn't imported inside the sh script. Value is returned from the script to it or is it because even it's defined outside but it's used under script { } part.

Comment: problem with double quotes(""") is that it's harder then do string manipulation etc.

Comment: ${BUILD_NUMBER} is a bash variable. You can check all bash variables provided by Jenkins here: `url-to-your-jenkinsl/env-vars.html/` or by passing "env" in your shell script in Jenkins.

Comment: what exact is harder? if you mean escaping bash variables - yes it could be problematic sometimes. Try to use groovy, is most natural for Jenkins.

Comment: Ok. Now that's explains why ${BUILD_NUMBER} is accepted. I stand corrected.

Not escaping bash variables but doing shell scripting. using single quotes(''') vs. double quotes(""") when doing shell script string manipulation is way easier. i got tons of trouble with double quotes.